# Matrix multiplication in recurrent neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, matrices

I was looking at a [tutorial](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-2-implementing-a-language-model-rnn-with-python-numpy-and-theano/) for recurrent neural networks in Python, and I have a question in regards to multiplying matrices of different sizes. Specifically, why does S[t] have 100 elements in it?

> `s[t] = np.tanh(self.U[:,x[t]] + self.W.dot(s[t-1]))`

Earlier in the tutorial, the author lists the dimensions for each variable:

> \begin{aligned} x_t & \in \mathbb{R}^{8000} \\ o_t & \in \mathbb{R}^{8000} \\ s_t & \in \mathbb{R}^{100} \\ U & \in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times 8000} \\ V & \in \mathbb{R}^{8000 \times 100} \\ W & \in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times 100} \\ \end{aligned}

From how I understand the above line of code, it multiplies U by x[t] and adds it to the product of W and s[t-1], then computes tanh for each element.

Sources like [this](http://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/matrix-addition.aspx) say that you cannot add matrices of different dimensions, however that seems to be what is happening here (because multiplication is just repeated addition). In fact, it seems that U is 2D and x[t] is 1D. How are these added? Also, how is the sum of the two products then 100 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix-by-matrix multiplication is very different from scalar-by-scalar. It has no connection to repeated addition, and in fact isn't even commutative: it's entirely possible that $AB \neq BA$. It's only called multiplication because it has some similar properties to repeated addition of scalars.

Matrix multiplication requires that the *inner dimensions match*. Nothing more, nothing less. You can multiply an (a×b) matrix by a (b×c) matrix, for instance, and the result is an (a×c) matrix. For the full details, [Wikipedia has a good summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

In addition, that code isn't adding or multiplying $U$ and $x[t]$. Rather, it's removing one dimension from $U$, taking only the columns (or rows depending on your definitions) which correspond to 1s in $x[t]$.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Is there any way to achieve similar results on a per-element basis? Meaning avoiding using matrix multiplication. P.S. Because x[t] is a one-hot vector, it is equivalent to multiplying U and x[t].

Comment: @APCoding Selecting only a single column/row from a matrix is, it turns out, very different from multiplying it! Multiplying by a one-hot vector zeroes out some columns/rows but doesn't remove them. So the resulting dimension is different.

Comment: @APCoding All modern machine learning algorithms are based on matrices and vectors in some way, *especially* neural networks. Keeping track of every weight and bias individually is a Very Bad Idea given the scale of even tiny toy networks. If you want to work with neural networks, you should read up a bit on vectors and matrices and how they interact.